# How to convert string into variable name in Python (tkinter)

Tags: python

Ok this is what I am trying to do.

```
import tkinter

def abc(buttonNumber):
    buttonNumber["text"] = rating[i]

b11 = tkinter.Button(top, text = "Name", command = abc("b11"))
```

Here, I want `abc` funciton to get called when someone click b11 button.

But I cannot use `abc(b11)` because, b11 is not defined yet.

So, If i use `abc("b11")` instead, I get this error:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Do I need to convert string into variable? If yes how?

Or It can be done in a better way?

Comment: Store buttons in a dictionary or list, and pass the index to the function.

Comment: @internet_user Sorry, but I do not understand how. I am new to tkinter. I do not understand it's documentation, can you tell me how in an Answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemple using dictionary to variable name

```
dict = {}
x = "fizz" // variable name fizz
dict[x] = 4 // variable value
```

"Use {} curly brackets to construct the dictionary, and [] square brackets to index it. Separate the key and value with colons : and with commas , between each pair. Keys must be quoted As with lists we can print out the dictionary by printing the reference to it. A dictionary maps a set of objects (keys) to another set of objects (values). A Python dictionary is a mapping of unique keys to values. Dictionaries are mutable, which means they can be changed. The values that the keys point to can be any Python value. Dictionaries are unordered, so the order that the keys are added doesn't necessarily reflect what order they may be reported back.", [font](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python)

your exemple:

```
x = "b11 "
dict[x] = null // value of the button (pointer), set value in the future
b11 = tkinter.Button(top, text = "Name", command = abc(dict["b11"]))
```